# Nivo Slider not working as it should in WebKit (chrome and safari)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, nivo-slider

I'm using Nivo Slider on http://tinyurl.com/5wtrau2 and I am unable to get the slideshow to operate correctly in Webkit, Chrome or Safari(mac). The slider transitions by making the current image a background image of the container and then randomly fades each box. It appears like the background image is reloading and there's a slight pause.

Comment: it would help to see your script. Do you call the plugin within a       $(function(){}); statement to make sure everything has loaded?

Comment: Combining all your CSS and JavaScript plugins into one big file may be efficient but it's not very conducive to troubleshooting.   Do you still have this problem when you include the various plugins separately?

Comment: @TommyBs, enclosing the script in a `$(function(){});`, the same as a `$(document).ready(function(){});`, does **not** make sure "everything" has loaded, it just ensures the DOM has been loaded.  If you want to make sure all page assets, including images, have been loaded, you would use a `$(window).load(function(){});`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm pretty sure that the issue isn't anything to do with the loading because it works fine in other browsers - the issue appears to be in Chrome and Safari only. @Sparky672 - Why would the problem disappear if I include the plugins separately?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't recall saying the problem _would_ disappear... I recall _asking you_ if you'd see them same.  Semantics aside, if you include each of them separately, you can at least troubleshoot much more effectively and intelligently.  You could remove or add them back one at a time to see which one is causing the problem, for example.  Don't you want to know if Nivo, all by itself, along with your parameters, is still acting funny in Webkit?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Sparky672 and I beg your pardon for misquoting you. I'm using a cms application I wrote and can add/remove the plugins with a few mouse clicks. I have already tried Nivo on it's own (without any other plugins loaded) and it behaves the same. Anyway I'm going to add the images into the html file rather than append them after the document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the slideshow images with javascript/jquery and then invoking the Nivo Slider seems to have been the issue here for Windows Safari. I added the images into the html file and the problem was resolved, however it is still an issue with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I used Google and found this: http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/561-flashing-before-transitions-in-mac-chrome#comment_13013897